# How to turn multiple value within a period in a pandas df into their corresponding "weight" for that period?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

So I have a pandas table like this:

| DateTime | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Day 1 - Time 1 | 4 |
| Day 1 - Time 2 | 3 |
| Day 1 - Time 3 | 3 |
| Day 2 - Time 1 | 10 |
| Day 2 - Time 2 | 10 |
| Day 3 - Time 1 | 184 |
| Day 4 ... | ... |

I want to turn it into this

| DateTime | Score | DailyScoreWeight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Day 1 - Time 1 | 4 | 0.4 |
| Day 1 - Time 2 | 3 | 0.3 |
| Day 1 - Time 3 | 3 | 0.3 |
| Day 2 - Time 1 | 10 | 0.5 |
| Day 2 - Time 2 | 10 | 0.5 |
| Day 3 - Time 1 | 184 | 1.0 |
| Day 4 ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new `Series`, so possible divide by original column:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

s = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='d', key='DateTime'))['Score'].transform('sum')
df['new'] = df['Score'].div(s)
```